# Date and time type for use with Protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm considering to use Protocol Buffers for data exchange between a Linux and a Windows based system.

Whats the recommended format for sending date/time (timestamp) values? The field should be small when serialized.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Although you aren't saying which languages you are using or what kind of precision you need, I would suggest using [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) encoded into a `int64`. It is fairly easy to handle in most languages and platforms (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724228(VS.85).aspx) for a Windows example), and Protobufs will use a [varint-encoding](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html) keeping the size small without limiting the representable range too much.

Comment: uses only 4 bytes until 2038... can't beat that

Comment: Huh? What are you talking about?

Comment: Unix time consumes only 4 bytes, which is quite an efficient encoding.  But for dates after 2038, it requires more than 4 bytes

Comment: Unix time is not specified in terms of how many bytes it takes up, it is defined as the number of seconds since the epoch. Traditionally it has been represented as a 32-bit integer, but most operating system uses 64-bit integers today.

Comment: The wikipedia page on Unix time contains more info, in case you are interested: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: My point is:  If you use Unix Time in protobuf you will use only 4 bytes... meaning Unix Time is good.... that's all I'm saying!  As an aside I'm adding a caveat that for after 2038, the 4 bytes will no longer be enough

Comment: Isn't it 5?  Varint encoding.

Comment: then will i have to store the timezone information separately?

Comment: Yes. Unix time does not take timezones into account.

Comment: No. You don't generally need to store the timezone. Your display function can take the current timezone and convert it.

Comment: Why use int and not uint?

Comment: Is there than any advantage to using protobuf Timestamp?

Answer (score 215):

There is `Timestamp` message type since protobuf 3.0, that's how to create it in model:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message MyMessage {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp my_field = 1;
}
```

`timestamp.proto` file contains examples of Timestamp using, including related to Linux and Windows programs.

> Example 1: Compute Timestamp from POSIX `time()`.

```
Timestamp timestamp;
timestamp.set_seconds(time(NULL));
timestamp.set_nanos(0);
```

> Example 2: Compute Timestamp from POSIX `gettimeofday()`.

```
struct timeval tv;
gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

Timestamp timestamp;
timestamp.set_seconds(tv.tv_sec);
timestamp.set_nanos(tv.tv_usec * 1000);
```

> Example 3: Compute Timestamp from Win32 `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()`.

```
FILETIME ft;
GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);
UINT64 ticks = (((UINT64)ft.dwHighDateTime) << 32) | ft.dwLowDateTime;

// A Windows tick is 100 nanoseconds. Windows epoch 1601-01-01T00:00:00Z
// is 11644473600 seconds before Unix epoch 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
Timestamp timestamp;
timestamp.set_seconds((INT64) ((ticks / 10000000) - 11644473600LL));
timestamp.set_nanos((INT32) ((ticks % 10000000) * 100));
```

Comment: What about JavaScript?

Comment: Not sure this is worth a whole answer, but the question asks about timestamps and dates, so consider google.type.Date for when you don't need higher precision.

Comment: @micseydel: OP asked for a "small" data type. google.type.Date is 3 ints and has less precision than simply sending an int64 with a Unix Timestamp. There are very few cases where google.type.Date is desirable, except for its easy of human readability. Of course, the binary format of Protobuf will combine the 3 ints as best it can but in general it doesn't seem ideal if size matters.

Comment: Doesn't the conversion from seconds to nanoseconds look off here? tv.tv_usec * 1000 gives us the value in milliseconds, not nanos.

Answer (score 11):

In the latest protobuf version (3.0) - For C#, Timestamp a WellKnownType is available. Check [this](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/well-known-types/timestamp)

Comment: That's slightly missleading, it seems that feature isn't C# exclusive, but rather language independent. Here it's for Java: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java