# How to import message names in protobuf models?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Let's say, I want to use standard `google.protobuf.Timestamp` type, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574716/date-and-time-type-for-use-with-protobuf/42922721#42922721). I need to use it several times:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message MyMessage {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp my_field_1 = 1;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp my_field_2 = 2;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp my_field_3 = 3;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp my_field_4 = 4;
}
```

It feels so tedious to repeat all these `google.protobuf` stuff by hand! Is there some way to import this pesky `google.protobuf.Timestamp` once and just to use `Timestamp` in all field definitions?

For example, something like this would be so nice!

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

import google.protobuf.Timestamp

message MyMessage {
    Timestamp my_field_1 = 1;
    Timestamp my_field_2 = 2;
    Timestamp my_field_3 = 3;
    Timestamp my_field_4 = 4;
}
```

Sure, problem isn't limited by using `Timestamp` type, it would be great to use some kind of import for any message.

Comment: Not AFAIK, no (unless you change your own namespace to match); sorry, that probably doesn't help...