# How to set google.protobuf.Timestamp to null?

Tags: timestamp, protocol-buffers, grpc

How to represent a null timestamp in Google ProtoBuf?

I am reading DateTime's from a postgreSQL database--some of which are null--into protobuf TimeStamps.

```
message test {
  google.protobuf.TimestampValue TransactionTime =1;
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no such animal as google.protobuf.TimestampValue.

Any help is most appreciated.

TIA

Comment: It should be `google.protobuf.Timestamp`, please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574716/date-and-time-type-for-use-with-protobuf

Comment: @JayantSeth Yes...but how to handle null value for Timestamp?

Comment: thats interesting, I think you'll have to handle this logic in your application like: instead of using timestamp you can use string and then convert it to timestamp at application end and when the value is null just send empty string ''

Comment: @JayantSeth is correct. IIUC you cannot use null. Protobuf messages are either present (possibly default) valued or optional but they can't be null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @JayantSeth pointed out, you should use `google.protobuf.Timestamp`.

Since `Protobuf` forbids to set field to `null`, you could use a default value to present `null` in your application. There are two fields in [`message Timestamp`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto):

```
message Timestamp {
  // Represents seconds of UTC time since Unix epoch
  // 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Must be from 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z to
  // 9999-12-31T23:59:59Z inclusive.
  int64 seconds = 1;

  // Non-negative fractions of a second at nanosecond resolution. Negative
  // second values with fractions must still have non-negative nanos values
  // that count forward in time. Must be from 0 to 999,999,999
  // inclusive.
  int32 nanos = 2;
}
```

The default value of type `int64` and `int32` both are `0`. Therefore, if some value read from Postgres is null, then you could set it to 0.

```cpp
Timestamp timestamp;
timestamp.set_seconds(0);
timestamp.set_nanos(0);
```

And in your application, you could treat `timestamp(0)` as `null`.

Comment: Great answer. However, one of my timestamps is for a person's birthdate. How would I manage a birthdate of 1970-01-01 (which I actually do have) ? Thanks.

Comment: Setting `timestamp` to default value(e.g. `0`) is one way to go, you could also set `timestamp` to another value to represent `null`, which depends on application logic. In your case, you are using `timestamp` to handle birthdate(I guess), you could use max value of int32 as default value, which is `2038-01-19`(of course it still depends on your application to check if it's acceptable)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @ramsay's answer. In Python, a good way to check for null would be to check either the seconds or nanoseconds field as such:

```py
from google.protobuf import timestamp_pb2
timestamp = timestamp_pb2.Timestamp()
 
if timestamp.seconds:
    # A valid non-null date was passed
else:
    # The date field was left empty; act accordingly.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just omit sending the value. Then you can use `hasTransactionTime` to check if it was set. Fields that are messages like timestamp can be omitted and that can be detected in code.

Use this proto:

```
message test {
  google.protobuf.Timestamp TransactionTime = 1;
}
```